# I tried to use linkText locator to click button but it didn't work

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I tried to use linkText locator to click " Sınav Modülü" button but it didn't work, i also tried xpath but i guess it was work. Can you help?

```
<a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-book-open"><path d="M2 3h6a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v14a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H2z"></path><path d="M22 3h-6a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v14a3 3 0 0 1 3-3h7z"></path></svg> 
    Sınav Modülü
    </a>
```

---

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Sınav Modülü")).click();
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Sınav Modülü")).click();   I used this line code to click button.

Comment: Can you share some more above html code?

Comment: Can you check if there is iframe present in the web page.

Comment: I did now you can check

Answer (score 0):

Try using below xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sınav Modülü")).click();
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: `By.xPath` should be `By.xpath` in above `p` should be in small letter

Comment: yes, it didn't work

Comment: what `error` are you getting ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)

Comment: I have updated answer, try using that.

Comment: It didn't work. I put sysout("error") after clicking button it didn't work either. Maybe it's because clicking operation? driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
   //*[@class='feather-feather-book-open']/..  //for parent to svg

  //*[@class='feather-feather-book-open']   // for svg element
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[@class='feather-feather-book-open']")).click();

Comment: dont use svg.. use *

Comment: no, not working

Comment: It didn't work. I put sysout("error") after clicking button it didn't work either. Maybe it's because clicking operation? driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath -

`//svg[contains(text(),'Sınav Modülü')]`

So the code will look like -

`WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[contains(text(),'Sınav Modülü')]")); e.click();`

Comment: no, didn't work

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: ı put it after question, you can check

Comment: I put sysout("error") after clicking button it didn't work either. Maybe it's because clicking operation? driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();